# Pushing a window into focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I'm developing a small menubar application and I want to display the settings window when the corresponding NSMenuItem is pressed.

I currently have the following IBAction assigned to the menu item:

```
@IBAction func settingsButtonPressed(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    settingsView.makeKeyAndOrderFront(sender)
}
```

This displays the window, but doesn't push it into focus, so it's displayed behind the currently active window, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for.

I had a suspicion that this might have been due to the fact that the `Application is agent` target property is set to `YES`, but this actually has no effect on the outcome.

Could there be anything to be done with the window in the XIB file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your app is not the active app. It should work to call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` in addition to making the window key and ordering it front.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Adding `NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)` right after the makeKeyAndOrderFront call looks and works just fine :)